# Upsert and get value consistently

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to create an Employer entry for a corresponding User whether or not an Employer exists.  I have tried to use both:

```
employer.update(userIdQuery, employerData, {upsert: true})
employer.findAndModify(userIdQuery, [], employerData, {upsert: true})
```

Both of these work, but the results I get back are inconsistent between inserting and updating.  For example, if the record does not exist with `findAndModify`I get back:

```
{ value: null,
  lastErrorObject: 
  { updatedExisting: false,
    n: 1,
    upserted: 5668620a12fce919dba35275 },
  ok: 1 }
```

If the record already exists, I get

```
{ value: 
  { _id: 5668602212fce919dba35274,
    userId: 566860228461901b42d2a06d,
    org: 'The Org' },
  lastErrorObject: { updatedExisting: true, n: 1 },
  ok: 1 }
```

What I would like to do is return the employer value once the insert/update is complete.

I could do this by trying to find the employer value and inserting it if it's not there, then getting the new value in some other way but I'm trying to avoid extra formatting of the data and any extra queries if I can.

Is there any consistent way to do an upsert and get the inserted/updated value in the same format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ops` value returned from writes do get written documents. These are only returned for `insertOne`, `insertMany`, and `replaceOne`, but the `replaceOne` method will work perfectly for this.

```
employer.replaceOne(userIdQuery, employerData, {upsert: true})
```

This returns results similar to `insertOne` which includes `ops` which will have the new document (whether inserted or updated).